# Default News Feed on Visual Studio Start Page (C# Profile)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Whenever I install Visual Studio 2005 or 2008 and choose the C# profile, the "News" portion of the start page defaults to "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=45192&clcid=409".

I like the start page and like to reference it and like the content of the default MSDN C# news feed (there is a lot of good stuff there) provided, but the feed hasn't been updated since March 2008.

**Is there a more up to date MSDN C# News feed?** This one is titled "MSDN: Visual C#" and subtitled "The latest information for developers on Visual C#" leading me to think it is the appropriate "official" MS C# news feed. **Or, is this just a dummy feed MS throws in and developers are expected to customize their VS start page with their preferred feeds?** I don't have a problem doing that - I just thought the one provided looked promising (if it was up to date).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just change the feed to whatever suits you, and whatever is most interesting to you.  There are several sites that can [combine several feeds into one](http://ask.metafilter.com/16678/Combine-RSS-feeds-into-new-feed), and that might also be a good option.

Answer (score 8):

So I realize this is an ancient thread now, but I happened across it searching for the same thing.  I recently installed VS2008 on a second machine, and the URL it is using *has* been updated (as recently as 12/08/2009, and is:

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=84795&clcid=409

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of the Microsoft C# Teams blogs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336723.aspx